# return column differences when comparing rows in grouped data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to do a pairwise comparison per group and return the row with a mismatch and which columns are different. Below is a sample dataset to explain the problem my actual data will have many more rows and columns.

```
data=structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), Common_1 = c("A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B"), Common_2 = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D"), Common_3 = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"), G = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), var_1 = c(1, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 5, 1, 4), var_2 = c("lev1", 
"lev1", "lev2", "lev2", "lev1", "lev2", "lev2", "lev1", "lev1", 
"lev2", "lev2", "lev2", "lev2", "lev1", "lev1", "lev1", "lev1", 
"lev1", "lev2", "lev2"), var_3 = c("on", "on", "on", "off", "off", 
"on", "on", "on", "off", "off", "on", "on", "on", "off", "off", 
"on", "on", "on", "off", "off"), var_4 = c("up", "up", "down", 
"down", "up", "down", "up", "down", "up", "up", "up", "up", "down", 
"down", "up", "up", "up", "up", "down", "down")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

`ID` is a unique identifier, `Common_1`,`Common_2`,`Common_3`are grouping variables, `G` is the group that I want to make the comparisons between and finally the rest of the columns `var_1:var_4` are the columns to determine differences. The process would be to compare each row in `G=0` to `G=1` and if there is a difference in any of the `var` columns return the `ID` combination of the mismatch and which  columns differ.

Here are the desired results for  `Common_1=A`,`Common_2=C`,`Common_3=X` it has the `ID` for rows `G=0`, all the grouping variables, the `ID` for the `G=1` mismatch and indicator variables showing which columns differed.

```
results=structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4), Common_1 = c("A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A"), Common_2 = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"
), Common_3 = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X"), G = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), var_1 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), var_2 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1), var_3 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), var_4 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1), ID_diff = c(2, 5, 2, 5, 2, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Update:** Added explanation of results

I am doing a pairwise comparison of `G=0` to `G=1`. The first two rows of results are derived like so:
Same overall group `Common_1=A`,`Common_2=C`,`Common_3=X`

now  compare `ID=1` to `ID=2`

`var_1` is different so a 1 is placed in the var_1 column and rest are zero.  `ID_diff=2` because that is the ID that differs from `ID=1`

compare `ID=1` to `ID=5`

`var_1`  and `var_3` are different so a 1 is placed in each column and rest are zero. `ID_diff=5` because that is the ID that differs from `ID=1`

I tried writing a function to loop through each case with `G=0` and compare to each case where `G=1` but got stuck extracting the mismatch info, any help is appreciated.

Results from Ronak Shah's solution which works but I am having trouble  displaying the results correctly.

```
> var_col <- grep('^var', names(data))
> 
> apply_fun <- function(tmp) {
+     df1 <- subset(tmp, G == 0)
+     df2 <- subset(tmp, G == 1)
+     lapply(seq(nrow(df1)), function(x) {
+         df3 <- df1[rep(x, nrow(df2)), ]
+         df3$ID_diff <- df2$ID
+         df3[var_col] <- +(df1[rep(x, nrow(df2)), var_col] != df2[var_col])
+         df3
+     })
+ }
> 
> 
> library(dplyr)
> data %>%
+     group_by(across(starts_with('Common'))) %>%
+     summarise(data = apply_fun(cur_data_all())) %>%
+     ungroup %>%
+     select(data) %>%
+     tidyr::unnest(data)
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'Common_1', 'Common_2', 'Common_3' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 22 x 10
      ID Common_1 Common_2 Common_3     G var_1[,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4] var_2[,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4] var_3[,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4] var_4[,1]  [,2]
   <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>     <int> <int> <int> <int>     <int> <int> <int> <int>     <int> <int> <int> <int>     <int> <int>
 1     1 A        C        X            0         1     0     0     0         1     0     0     0         1     0     0     0         1     0
 2     1 A        C        X            0         1     0     1     0         1     0     1     0         1     0     1     0         1     0
 3     3 A        C        X            0         0     1     0     1         0     1     0     1         0     1     0     1         0     1
 4     3 A        C        X            0         0     1     1     1         0     1     1     1         0     1     1     1         0     1
 5     4 A        C        X            0         0     1     1     1         0     1     1     1         0     1     1     1         0     1
 6     4 A        C        X            0         0     1     0     1         0     1     0     1         0     1     0     1         0     1
 7     7 A        D        X            0         1     0     0     1         1     0     0     1         1     0     0     1         1     0
 8     8 A        D        X            0         1     1     0     0         1     1     0     0         1     1     0     0         1     1
 9     9 A        D        X            0         1     1     1     1         1     1     1     1         1     1     1     1         1     1
10    10 A        D        X            0         1     0     1     1         1     0     1     1         1     0     1     1         1     0
# ... with 12 more rows, and 3 more variables: [,3] <int>, [,4] <int>, ID_diff <dbl>
```

Comment: I am finding difficult to understand your question. Can you explain how you get the output  in `results` ?

Comment: I edited the question to include an explanation of the desired results. Thanks for taking the time to look at it.

Comment: Within one group (`Common_1=A`, `Common_2=C`,`Common_3=X` is one group) you want to compare all the rows of `G = 0` with all the rows of `G = 1` rows and return only the rows where difference is observed?

Comment: Yes, but also which columns are different  and with what `G=1` `ID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this :

We create a function which compares every row of `G == 0` with every row of `G == 1` and changes the values to 1/0 in `var_col` based on the comparison.

```
var_col <- grep('^var', names(data))

apply_fun <- function(tmp) {
  df1 <- subset(tmp, G == 0)
  df2 <- subset(tmp, G == 1)
  lapply(seq(nrow(df1)), function(x) {
    df3 <- df1[rep(x, nrow(df2)), ]
    df3$ID_diff <- df2$ID
    df3[var_col] <- +(df1[rep(x, nrow(df2)), var_col] != df2[var_col])
    df3
  })
}
```

Apply data by group :

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(across(starts_with('Common'))) %>%
  summarise(data = apply_fun(cur_data_all())) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(data) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(data)

# A tibble: 22 x 10
#      ID Common_1 Common_2 Common_3     G var_1 var_2 var_3 var_4 ID_diff
#   <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>   <dbl>
# 1     1 A        C        X            0     1     0     0     0       2
# 2     1 A        C        X            0     1     0     1     0       5
# 3     3 A        C        X            0     0     1     0     1       2
# 4     3 A        C        X            0     0     1     1     1       5
# 5     4 A        C        X            0     0     1     1     1       2
# 6     4 A        C        X            0     0     1     0     1       5
# 7     7 A        D        X            0     1     0     0     1       6
# 8     8 A        D        X            0     1     1     0     0       6
# 9     9 A        D        X            0     1     1     1     1       6
#10    10 A        D        X            0     1     0     1     1       6
# … with 12 more rows
```

`cur_data_all()` and `across` needs latest installation of `dplyr`. My `packageVersion('dplyr')` is `1.0.1’`.

Comment: I am getting weird display results when I assign the dplyr pipeline to an object the numbers are incorrect.  When I display it to the console they are correct but the `var` columns are duplicated 4 times.

Comment: with this warning ``summarise()` regrouping output by 'Common_1', 'Common_2', 'Common_3' (override with `.groups` argument)``

Comment: @tetime you can ignore the warning, that is not an issue. Did you assign the result back? `data1 <- data %>% group_by(across(starts_with('Common')))....` Are you using the same data to test this or different data?

Comment: Yes same data  I posted the output in my original question

Comment: @tetime That is weird. I rechecked again and get the same output as shown in my post. What is your `packageVersion('tidyr')` ? Mine is `#[1] ‘1.1.2’`

Comment: I think that was it  I fully updated `R` and `tidyr` and it is working  now. Thanks for all the help this is a great solution!